# WebClient's DownloadString(url) returns 403 forbidden when run from Azure Functions but works fine on local debugging with azure-functions-core-tools

Tags: c#, azure-functions, webclient, azure-functions-core-tools

I am not able to figure out why my code runs fine on my local but doesn't on azure functions.

This is the code snippet

```
        using (var client = new WebClient ())
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Fetching html from {url}");
            
            try
            {
               var response = client.DownloadString(url);
                baseHtmlBasePageList.Add(response);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The URL I am trying to hit is https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/20171.
I am trying to determine where the issue could be.. like

1. Is Redfin able to differentiate between a request coming from Azure vs my local machine and respond differently?
2. Is it some setting on Azure that I need to set explicitly?

The code/function itself is very simple. Its a function that takes url like the example mentioned above, fetches the html by calling the DownloadString(url) method and returns the first 20 chars from the returned string.

I do understand that WebClient is deprecated but can we say for certain that that is why the behavior is not consistent between my local machine and Azure?

Comment: Hello Rohit, could you please provide full code and I believe `WebClient` is deprecated, we have to use `HttpClient`.

Comment: I added additional info to my question in response to your comment. Thanks.